# How to list all permissions granted to a specific principal on GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

GCP IAM page displays project-wide permissions and principals.

I've granted Object Admin permission to user@example.com to a specific GCS bucket. This permission is not visible on the IAM page.

How do I list all permissions granted to user@example.com across all resources using console or `gcloud` CLI?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like this can be done with the gcloud asset command: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/asset/search-all-iam-policies

Eg. a basic example query for a single project:

```
gcloud asset search-all-iam-policies --scope=projects/<project> --query="policy:<email>"
```

The output is quite verbose, but does what you want, I think.